# Why Kafka so fast

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have same hardware, to use Kafka or our current solution(ServiceMix/Camel). Is there any difference? Can Kafka handle "bigger" data than it? Why?

There is a article to talk about how fast could it be? But I still don't get clearly why Kafka is so fast comparing to other solutions?
[Benchmarking Apache Kafka: 2 Million Writes Per Second (On Three Cheap Machines)](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines)

Comment: Thee is a thread on Quora that discusses this in detail:
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Kafka-so-fast

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Kafka is fast for a number of reasons. To name a few.

- **Zero Copy** - See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy basically it
  calls the OS kernal direct rather than at the application layer to move
  data fast.
- **Batch Data in Chunk**s - Kafka is all about batching the
  data into chunks. This minimises cross machine latency with all the
  buffering/copying that accompanies this.
- **Avoids Random Disk Access** - as Kafka is an immutable commit log it does not need to rewind the disk and do many random I/O operations and can just access the disk in a sequential manner. This enables it to get similar speeds from a
  physical disk compared with memory.
- **Can Scale Horizontally** - The
  ability to have thousands of partitions for a single topic spread
  among thousands of machines means Kafka can handle huge loads.