# Disk persistence and replication?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

> Message sent to Kafka is written to disk and replicated for
>   fault-tolerance.

I am not sure when message is written to disc, why replication(partition) is required and how it helps ?

Also Kafka is said to be high in throughput, Does not writing to disk impact performance ? Is it configurable to have message just in memory but not in disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post by Jay Kreps (who is one of the original architects of Kafka while he was at LinkedIn) explains how Kafka is engineered uniquely as a commit log which can do "2 million writes per second on three cheap machines" and yield much higher messaging rates than traditional message brokers which are not engineered this way.

https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

Kafka has configurable parameters that control how often page cache is flushed to disk. It is not possible to run Kafka without eventually writing to disk. Kafka also caches messages in memory for performance so it can give high throughput with reads from memory while still guaranteeing no message loss from persistence to disk and clustered replication of data for fault tolerance.

Comment: Actually my main question is kafka is persisting the message in disc, what is the need for replication ? How does it help ?

Comment: Replication is for fault tolerance, not performance. It means you don't loose data and the system keeps working if the server dies. Partitioning (I.e. Sharding) is for performance because it stores the data across multiple servers. Kafka does both replication and partitioning so you get both high performance and reliability.

Comment: I understand Partitioning is for performance. What I am asking is when Kafka already persisting message in disc then there is no chance of data lost even if server dies. Then why replication of same message/data across node is required ?

Comment: Because the disk can die too. Also it will take some time to repair the server so the data is not available to read while the server is dead. In Kafka another server just immediately takes over for the failed one and there is no loss of service for consumers

Comment: Ok start getting it. Is replication on another node happen both on disc and in memory ?

Comment: Yes replicated data sent to the other nodes is also on disk and in page cache memory

Comment: @Hansn Jesperson Actually i am thinking other way around now. If we are already replicating data across nodes in memory then why do we need to store in disk  and why its mandatory? Also when these messages on disk gets purged ?

Comment: Its mandatory because you don’t pay a significant performance penalty for it and you get a lot of extra features and value from persisting all messages in order. The messages get purged in any 1of3 ways: 1) when your app explicitly purges them 2) when the retention period on the topic is exceeded 3) on “compacted” topics, old messages are deleted when new messages with the same key is published

Comment: Thanks. Can you please look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390311/kafka-cluster-workflow-summary ?